# NullPointException Virtual Method

Tags: java, android

When i run my app, it shows logcat :-

```
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063): Process: com.quickblox.q_municate, PID: 20063
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.quickblox.q_municate/ui.splash.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:137)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at com.quickblox.q_municate_core.utils.PrefsHelper.<init>(PrefsHelper.java:48)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at ui.splash.SplashActivity.<init>(SplashActivity.java:38)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
07-13 17:31:10.418: E/AndroidRuntime(20063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
```

And my code:-

SplashActivity:-

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity {

private static final String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private FacebookHelper facebookHelper;
public String userEmail;
public String userPassword;
public PrefsHelper prefshelper= new PrefsHelper(this);
public static void start(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addActions();

    facebookHelper = new FacebookHelper(this, savedInstanceState, new FacebookSessionStatusCallback());

    userEmail = prefshelper.getPref(PrefsHelper.PREF_USER_EMAIL);
    userPassword = prefshelper.getPref(PrefsHelper.PREF_USER_PASSWORD);

    boolean isRememberMe = prefshelper.getPref(PrefsHelper.PREF_REMEMBER_ME, false);

    if (isRememberMe) {
        checkStartExistSession(userEmail, userPassword);
    } else {
        startLanding();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    facebookHelper.onActivityStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isLoggedInToChat()) {
        startMainActivity();
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    facebookHelper.onActivityStop();
}

@Override
protected void onFailAction(String action) {
    super.onFailAction(action);
    startLanding();
}

private boolean isLoggedInToChat() {
    return QBChatService.isInitialized() && QBChatService.getInstance().isLoggedIn();
}

private void checkStartExistSession(String userEmail, String userPassword) {
    boolean isEmailEntered = !TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail);
    boolean isPasswordEntered = !TextUtils.isEmpty(userPassword);
    if ((isEmailEntered && isPasswordEntered) || (isLoggedViaFB(isPasswordEntered))) {
        runExistSession(userEmail, userPassword);
    } else {
        startLanding();
    }
}

private boolean isLoggedViaFB(boolean isPasswordEntered) {
    return isPasswordEntered && LoginType.FACEBOOK.equals(getCurrentLoginType());
}

private void addActions() {
    addAction(QBServiceConsts.LOGIN_SUCCESS_ACTION, new LoginSuccessAction());
    addAction(QBServiceConsts.LOGIN_AND_JOIN_CHATS_FAIL_ACTION, failAction);
    addAction(QBServiceConsts.LOGIN_FAIL_ACTION, failAction);
}

public boolean isLoggedViaFB() {
    return facebookHelper.isSessionOpened() && LoginType.FACEBOOK.equals(getCurrentLoginType());
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    facebookHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebookHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void startLanding() {
    LandingActivity.start(SplashActivity.this);
    finish();
}

private void runExistSession(String userEmail, String userPassword) {
    //check is token valid for about 1 minute
    if (AppSession.isSessionExistOrNotExpired(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(
            ConstsCore.TOKEN_VALID_TIME_IN_MINUTES))) {
        startMainActivity();
        finish();
    } else {
        doAutoLogin(userEmail, userPassword);
    }
}

private void doAutoLogin(String userEmail, String userPassword) {
    if (LoginType.EMAIL.equals(getCurrentLoginType())) {
        login(userEmail, userPassword);
    } else {
        FacebookHelper.logout();
        facebookHelper.loginWithFacebook();
    }
}

private void login(String userEmail, String userPassword) {
    QBUser user = new QBUser(null, userPassword, userEmail);
    QBLoginCommand.start(this, user);
}

private LoginType getCurrentLoginType() {
    return AppSession.getSession().getLoginType();
}

private void startMainActivity() {
    prefshelper.savePref(PrefsHelper.PREF_IMPORT_INITIALIZED, true);
    MainActivity.start(SplashActivity.this);
}

private class FacebookSessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened() && LoginType.FACEBOOK.equals(getCurrentLoginType())) {
            QBLoginRestWithSocialCommand.start(SplashActivity.this, QBProvider.FACEBOOK,
                    session.getAccessToken(), null);
        }
    }
}

private class LoginSuccessAction implements Command {

    @Override
    public void execute(Bundle bundle) {
        QBUser user = (QBUser) bundle.getSerializable(QBServiceConsts.EXTRA_USER);

        startMainActivity();

        AnalyticsUtils.pushAnalyticsData(SplashActivity.this, user, "User Sign In");

        finish();
    }
}
```

PrefsHelper:-

```
public class PrefsHelper {

    public static final String PREF_REMEMBER_ME = "remember_me";
    public static final String PREF_LOGIN_TYPE = "login_type";
    public static final String PREF_DIALOG_ID = "dialog_id";
    public static final String PREF_USER_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String PREF_USER_ID = "user_id";
    public static final String PREF_IS_LOGINED = "is_logined";
    public static final String PREF_USER_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String PREF_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS = "push_notifications";
    public static final String PREF_IMPORT_INITIALIZED = "import_initialized";
    public static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
    public static final String PREF_SIGN_UP_INITIALIZED = "sign_up_initialized";
    public static final String PREF_MISSED_MESSAGE = "missed_message";
    public static final String PREF_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String PREF_PUSH_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PREF_REG_USER_ID = "registered_push_user";
    public static final String PREF_USER_AGREEMENT = "user_agreement";
    public static final String PREF_JOINED_TO_ALL_DIALOGS = "joined_to_all_dialogs";

    public static final String PREF_PUSH_MESSAGE_NEED_TO_OPEN_DIALOG = "push_need_to_open_dialog";
    public static final String PREF_PUSH_MESSAGE_DIALOG_ID = "push_dialog_id";
    public static final String PREF_PUSH_MESSAGE_USER_ID = "push_user_id";

    public static final String PREF_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    public static final String PREF_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    public static final String PREF_RECEIVE_PUSH = "receive_push";
    public static final String PREF_IS_SUBSCRIBED_ON_SERVER = "subscribed_on_server";
    public static final String PREF_USER_FULL_NAME = "full_name";
    public static final String PREF_SESSION_TOKEN = "session_token";

    private final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private final SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private static PrefsHelper instance;

    public static PrefsHelper getPrefsHelper() {
        return instance;
    }

    public PrefsHelper(Context context) {
        instance = this;
        String prefsFile = context.getPackageName();
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(prefsFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public void delete(String key) {
        if (sharedPreferences.contains(key)) {
            editor.remove(key).commit();
        }
    }

    public void savePref(String key, Object value) {
        delete(key);

        if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
            editor.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Float) {
            editor.putFloat(key, (Float) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Long) {
            editor.putLong(key, (Long) value);
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            editor.putString(key, (String) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Enum) {
            editor.putString(key, value.toString());
        } else if (value != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Attempting to save non-primitive preference");
        }

        editor.commit();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T getPref(String key) {
        return (T) sharedPreferences.getAll().get(key);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T getPref(String key, T defValue) {
        T returnValue = (T) sharedPreferences.getAll().get(key);
        return returnValue == null ? defValue : returnValue;
    }

    public boolean isPrefExists(String key) {
        return sharedPreferences.contains(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just declared `public PrefsHelper prefshelper;` and you did not instantiate `prefshelper` that's why you are getting `NullPointerException` when you are accessing

```
     userEmail = prefshelper.getPref(PrefsHelper.PREF_USER_EMAIL);
```

Instantiate `prefshelper`, that should solve your problem.

```
       prefshelper = new Prefshelper(this.getApplicationContext());
```

**UPDATE**

I think the problem is you are instantiating the `prefshelper` before your `onCreate()`. You can define it there, but don't instantiate it

```
PrefsHelper prefshelper;
```

Inside you `onCreate()`, after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

do this

```
prefshelper = new PrefsHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Still Got error.. Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang,String.android.content.Context.getPackageName()' On Null Object Refrence

Comment: @MayankKhursija what did you change and what is the error? can you update the question with those details?

Comment: As u said I Instantiated

Comment: @MayankKhursija it will be helpful if you show the code rather than just saying what you did.

Comment: As you said i insantiated the Prefshelper And the Logcat showing is 'java.lang,String.android.content.Context.getPackageName()' On Null Object Refrence

Comment: @MayankKhursija and do you see that `java.lang,String.android.content.Context.getPackageName() On Null Object Refrence` is different from the original error you have got? You have done something wrong while instantiating, so show your changes in question.

Comment: @MayankKhursija I have updated the answer. Do it that way, it will work.

Comment: @MayankKhursija No issues :) I am glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't instantiate `PrefsHelper` anywhere. You're simply calling:

```
userEmail = prefshelper.getPref(PrefsHelper.PREF_USER_EMAIL);
userPassword = prefshelper.getPref(PrefsHelper.PREF_USER_PASSWORD);
```

in your `onCreate` but you never did `prefshelper = new PrefsHelper(this)` anywhere, so you get a `NullPointerException`.

(I'm assuming since `PrefHelper`'s constructor gets Context as an argument that you should pass it `this`, but I'm not sure without a deeper understanding on your intentions.)